# Model is not showing any values in .cshtml page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ViewModel which has to get & set methods from three tables at [HttpGet] request I only want to get the name-value pairs from one table only and show them on labels but when I return the object to .cshtml page this object is not showing anything but when I used breakpoint to check the values in the controller then it has all the values.

```
    [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult CreateNewAsset()
            {
                List<AssetVM> assetVMs = db.Physical_Asset_Properties.Select(x => new AssetVM
                {
                    PAP_Id=x.PAP_Id,
                   PAP_Value=x.PropertyName
                }).ToList();
                ViewBag.Message = "This Page is related to assets";
                return View(assetVMs);
            }
```

//This is View Page

```
@model List<OmniConnect.ViewModel.AssetVM.AssetVM>
<div id="phy_asset_properties" style="display:none">

                                <div class="row">
                                    @foreach(var item in Model)
                                    {
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>@item.PropertyName</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="@item.PAP_Id">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

Comment: When you breakpoint `return View(assetVMs)` what does `assetVMs` show?

Comment: it's showing all the 5 name values pairs which I want but in View, id is rendering but the name is not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `AssetVM` your using `PAP_Value` property and in the `View` your using `PropertyName` property from the original Class.

Should be:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>@item.PAP_Value</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="@item.PAP_Id">
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Haha, you're welcome.I have looked at the screen for hours before when it's been something so simple :)

Comment: same is the case with me